# How to copy files from a random folder into a destination folder in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch script to copy files from a random subfolder of a specific directory into a destination directory.

For example, there will be a number of files in their own subdirectory, for example

```
.../source/a/file.txt
.../source/b/file.txt
```

So there a number of these files, and I would like to randomly select one of them and have it copied into the new directory

```
.../destination/file.txt
```

So the file.txt in the destination is just being overwritten with other files that have the same name but different content.

I'm new to batch scripting and I can't quite figure out how to select each file from a random subfolder. I'd also like it to repeat every 30 seconds until I terminate the script, but I think it should be easy enough to just make a second script that calls this .bat file every 30 seconds once I get it going.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can do what you request.  Just set your source directory, destination directory, and your file name filter.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

pushd "...\source\"

:: Enumerate Files. Method 1
set "xCount=0"
for /r %%A in (file.txt) do if exist "%%~A" set /a "xCount+=1"
echo %xCount%

:: Select a Random File.
set /a "xIndex=%Random% %% %xCount%"
echo %xIndex%

:: Find an Copy that File. Method 1
set "xTally=0"
for /r %%A in (file.txt) do if exist "%%~A" (
    if "!xTally!" EQU "%xIndex%" (
        xcopy "%%~fA" "...\destination\file.txt" /Y
        goto End
    )
    set /a "xTally+=1"
)

:End
popd
endlocal
pause
```

Type [`xcopy /?`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to see all of its options.

Here are some alternate loop methodologies for the file enumeration.

```
:: Enumerate Files. Method 2
set "xCount=0"
for /f %%A in ('dir *.txt /a:-d /s ^| find "File(s)"') do set "xCount=%%~A"
echo %xCount%

:: Find an Copy that File. Method 2
set "xTally=0"
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir *.txt /a:-d /b /s') do (
    if "!xTally!" EQU "%xIndex%" (
        xcopy "%%~fA" "...\destination\file.txt" /Y
        goto End
    )
    set /a "xTally+=1"
)
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Enter into the directory that contain the folders
pushd \Fullpath\source
rem Create an array with all folders
set i=0
for /D %%a in (*) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set folder[!i!]=%%a
)
rem Randomly select one folder
set /A index=(%random%*i)/32768 + 1
rem Copy the desired file
copy "!folder[%index%]!\file.txt" "\Fullpath\destination" /Y
rem And return to original directory
popd
```

Answer (score 0):

The features of batch script is

1. It copies all files from source to destination folder with similar structure(even retains empty folders).
2. Can retain N number of days recent files in Archive folder(source) remaining files will be moved to backup folder(destination).
3. Can be scheduled to N number of days to N number of years.
4. Can be used in any Source to destination folder backup.
5. Source folder can add N number of folder any time and delete folder or files, but Destination folder always adds the folder and never deletes any folder or file.

---

```
@echo off
Set "sourcefolder=E:\Interfaces"
Set "destinationfolder=E:\BackupInterface"
If Exist %sourcefolder% (
For /F %%* In ('Dir /b /aD "%sourcefolder%" 2^>nul') do (If Not Exist "%destinationfolder%\%%*" ( RD /S /Q "%destinationfolder%\%%*")
xcopy /e /v /i /y /q "%sourcefolder%\%%*" "%destinationfolder%\%%*" 
forfiles /p "%sourcefolder%\%%*" /s  /d -30 /c "cmd /c del /Q /S  @file" )
) Else (echo.Source folder could not be found)
:end of batch
echo.&echo.finished!
```

---